# vba excel areas

Tags: excel, vba

How to store multiple areas in array (areas type)?

```
Dim SelAreas() As Areas
NumAreas = Selection.Areas.Count
ReDim SelAreas(1 To NumAreas)
    For i = 1 To NumAreas
        SelAreas(i) = Selection.Areas(i)
    Next i
```

the above code errs as invalid use of property.

I don't want to be stored in range array.

Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Balu.

Comment: To correct the syntax area you would need to write _Set SelAreas(i) = Selection.Areas(i)_ But then you will get run time error 13 because _Selection.Areas(i)_ is a range and _SelAreas(i)_ is of type _Areas_. Question is what do you want to do? So, please clarify that first.

Comment: I am creating charts by below type: 1st chart by all 1st columns of each area, 2nd chart by all 2nd columns each area. So I am copying each column of each area, next to each other. I am storing each area into an array of area type. So that I can copy all 1st columns from all area array and 2nd one etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the Areas Collection is a bunch of `Range`s.

You really need to make an array of range Objects like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Area As Range, ArrayOfAreas() As Range, i As Long
    ReDim ArrayOfAreas(1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Areas.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each Area In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Areas
        Set ArrayOfAreas(i) = Area
        i = i + 1
    Next Area
End Sub
```

Note we use `Set` because we are dealing with ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can we copy the first column of each area, for the 1st chart data and 2nd columns of each area for the 2nd chart etc., from this array.

Comment: for eg., I have 10 selections of range. each range has 7 columns and 5 rows. Can I take each column from each range and create charts, with the help of array.

Comment: @BalasubramanianSeshadri yes........................just get the info from each range.

Comment: Any pointers, to how to get info from each range. As the array stores with the info of rows and columns. Value2(1,1) (got from watch window)